# Most precise regex match

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to find of most precise regex for a string?
For e.g.
Lets say, I have 2 regex:

1) `.*bourne`
2) `.*ne`

If I try to match `Melbourne` with the above regex, it will match with both regex.

But more precise match will be the first regex. Similarly, there can be very complex regex.

Is there a way to find the most precise match?

Comment: Define "precise". Do you want the longest match? The longest regex?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: You should know what you want match,find the common ground . `Melbourne` will be more precise if just match itself.

Comment: From precise, I meant the most accurate match. Yes, may be the longest match. "Melbourne" itself is a regex, so if there is a regex with "Melbourne" than I should consider that regex as it is the exact match.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to find the most precise match?

The most "*precise*" match is the the one where the regex needs to process less data until it finds a match, in this case, `.*bourne`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't sorting the patterns in descending order of length solve the problem ?
For example, if Java is the language being used something like the following should be fine right (just sort the pattern in descending order of length and then return for first match)?

```
  public class TestPattern {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String text    ="Melbourne";

        System.out.println("Mtaching regex --> "+getMatchingRegex(text));
    }

    public static String getMatchingRegex(String text) {


        ArrayList<String> patterns = new ArrayList<String>();
        patterns.add(".*ne") ;
        patterns.add(".*urne") ;
        patterns.add(".*bourne") ;
        patterns.add(".*rne") ;

        Collections.sort(patterns, new StringComparator());


        for(String pattern:patterns) {
            if(Pattern.matches(pattern, text))
                return pattern;
        }

        return "No Regex matched";
    }

    public static class StringComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) 
        {
            return s2.length()-s1.length();
        }
    }
}
```